# ChartJS: Custom legend not showing Labels for Multi-Pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a Pie chart with multiple rings and created a Custom Legend function with below code:

```
function (chart) {
var text = [];
text.push('<ul class="list-inline ' + chart.id + '-legend">');
for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
    text.push('<li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-circle pr-1" style="color:' +
            chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '"></i>');
    if (chart.data.labels[i]) {
        text.push('<span class="font-weight-bold">' + chart.data.labels[i] + '</span>');
    }
    text.push('</li>');
}
text.push('</ul>');
return text.join('');
},
```

The above function is expected to show all the Labels from the PieChart, but it is showing only bulletpoints.

Here is the JSfille (https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/x03w2qbk/17/)

Comment: With some changes, I am able to show Labels but only from the first data / first ring. JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/x03w2qbk/17/

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels) out

Comment: No, I am not sure how this is useful to show Custom legend and relevant to this situation.

Comment: Now you're looping only through `chart.data.datasets[0]` eventhough you have 2 datasets. So loop also through `chart.data.datasets[1]` or make a loop that loops through all datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather labels from all datasets, you should include all datasets into your loop:

```
for(var j = 0; j < chart.data.datasets.length; j++){
  for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[j].data.length; i++) {
      text.push('<li class="list-inline-item"><small><i class="fas fa-circle pr-1" style="color:' +
              chart.data.datasets[j].backgroundColor[i] + '"></i>');
      if (chart.data.datasets[j].labels[i]) {
          text.push('<span class="font-weight-bold">' + chart.data.datasets[j].labels[i] + '</span>');
      }
      text.push('</small></li>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, it is giving me the first data labels only.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I must have missed something while testing the previous answer.

Comment: No probs. Yeah chart.js is a bit messy when you want something done your way. :)